# Springboot + JOOQ transaction rollback

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jooq

I am using jooq with spring boot 3. I am handling multiple database operations so I want to take transaction management. But somehow transaction management is not working. I mark the service method `@Transactional` but rollback is not happening. I want to add records in three tables while inserting records in the last table SQL exception occurs. But entry is not rollback from the first two tables.

Here is the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and config:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JooqConfiguration {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext context() {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
    }

    public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
        DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
        jooqConfiguration.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jooqConfiguration.setSQLDialect(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
        jooqConfiguration.setSettings(new Settings().withExecuteWithOptimisticLocking(true));

        return jooqConfiguration;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your transactional code? In particular, I'm interested in whether you're using jOOQ's transaction API.

Comment: @Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
  public Response createData() throws JsonProcessingException {}

Comment: Can you show the content of the method as well as how you run the jOOQ queries?